# How to use hasNextInt in Java to check if the entered value is integer or not?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that asks the user to enter age and loop until the age is positive or a number. When I enter negative number, the look works and it asks to enter the number again but when I enter letters like "xyz" instead, the loop doesn't work and and the program crashes.

```
public static void firstScannerMethod () {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //importing scanner class
        System.out.println("enter your age: ");
        boolean hasNextIntAge = scanner.hasNextInt(); //checking to see if next entered value is an integer
        int myAge = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); //handling enter
        while (myAge < 0 || !hasNextIntAge) { // if age is less than 0 or if age is not an integer, prompt again
            System.out.println("invalid age, try again");
            System.out.println("enter your age: ");
            myAge = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
            System.out.println("your age is " + myAge);
        scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Think carefully about your logic. At what point(s) in the process should `hasNextIntAge` have its value set? At what point(s) *does* it happen?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel hasNextIntAge gets its value (true or false) from the next input no? help me understand please?

Comment: Look at where you test if your scanner has another value, and where you read the next value from the scanner. Look at the order in which you are performing these steps.

Comment: I'm hoping that you only call this method once, or that you have no other methods that use Scanner with System.in. Closing any scanner that uses System.in closes System.in, and it's almost impossible to reopen it.

Comment: @NomadMaker yep. only a sample method. still cant figure out the logic though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the value of hasNextIntAge before calling the nextInt method. As a result, when nextInt gets a string value it throws an InputMismatchException. I have updated your code to set myAge only if the input is an integer.

```
public static void firstScannerMethod () {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter your age: ");
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("invalid age, try again");
        scanner.next();
    }
    int myAge = scanner.nextInt();
    while (myAge < 0) {
        System.out.println("invalid age, try again");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("invalid age, try again");
            scanner.next();
        }
        myAge = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("your age is " + myAge);
    scanner.close();
}
```